# Change header label "sign in" to "log in" in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, plugin, override-block

Can anyone help how to change header's "sign-in" label to "log-in" in Magento 2.

Comment: Could you please share the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way for change the label is Translation.

You need to just make i18N folder in your app/code/spacename/modulename and just create one CSV file en_US and give translation script over there.

See Example : en_US.csv

```
"Sign In","Login"
```

No need to override anything for the small change.

Comment: question is only about label change, right?

Comment: Yes it's only for label changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the 'create account' label with XML the code you have to paste

Go to app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

and place below code

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Resiter Account</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```