# how to override getlabel() function in Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Can anyone guide me how to override the getlabel() function in Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink  (Magento 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this by preference in your module 
  app/code/Manish/Ms/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" type="Manish\Ms\Block\Magento\Customer\Account\AuthorizationLink" />
</config>
```

Here is your block file where you will extends Magento block file as parent.

```
<?php

namespace Manish\Ms\Block\Magento\Customer\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface;

class AuthorizationLink extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink
{

/**
 * @return string
 */
    public function getLabel()
    {
       return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Sign Out') : __('Sign In');
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Manish Goswami, Here also you have to use plugin for the same because  here the function is public.

Comment: @ ammanchipavan you can also you plugin here if you want then please do let me know I will show the method.

Comment: By Using above code my default sign in is not displaying in front end

Comment: @DharmendraJadav you are also right adding new one also...

Comment: @ammanchipavan you need to call parent::getLabel() function as per needed.

Comment: @ammanchipavan You have make plugin for the same and also use around method for that method which you have to override.

Comment: @ammanchipavan you have to return some string from function to show..

Comment: Can anyone help solving this quesiton! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223608/how-to-change-sign-in-header-to-log-in-in-magento-2-using-pluging-to-override-th

Answer (score 1):

You have to [create module](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-module-in-magento-2/) for that
and add code in `app\code\Ketan\Kp\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" type="Ketan\Kp\Block\Magento\Customer\Account\AuthorizationLink" />

</config>
```

ovveride file `app\code\Ketan\Kp\Block\Magento\Customer\Account\AuthorizationLink.php`

```
<?php

namespace Ketan\Kp\Block\Magento\Customer\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface;

class AuthorizationLink extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink
{

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Sign Out') : __('Sign In');
    }
}
```

Run command : `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: @ KetanKp Borada, Here also you have to use plugin for the same because  here the function is public.